# why null (login pop up)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Probably it's something small i do not see...
I have a UserControls_LoginPopUp with one of the properties as:

```
public string urlForRedirecting {get; set;}
```

This user control contains a modalpopupextender and a method for login:

```
 public void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user = txtUser.Text;
    string passwordMD5 = UtilsStatic.GetMD5Hash(txtPassword.Text);
    int id = checkUserAtLogin(user, passwordMD5);
    if (id != -1)
    {
        //MySession.Current.userId = id;
        lblStatus.Text = "Autentificare reusita!";
        loginPopUp.Hide();

        //The user will be redirected
        Response.Redirect(this.urlForRedirecting);
        this.urlForRedirecting = "";
    }
    else
    {
        MySession.Current.userId = -1;
        lblStatus.Text = "Autentificare esuata!";
        loginPopUp.Show();
    }
}
```

Now, from another page, a user clicks a link, and a method is fired where the modal extender is shown so he can login. Please notice that i fill up the urlForRedirecting property:

```
 public void redirectToWishList(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (UtilsStatic.getUserLoggedInId() == -1)
    {
        ASP.usercontrols_loginpopup_ascx loginUserControl = (ASP.usercontrols_loginpopup_ascx)UtilsStatic.FindControlRecursive(Page, "loginPopUp");
        ModalPopupExtender modal = (ModalPopupExtender)loginUserControl.FindControl("loginPopUp");
        modal.Show();
        //put the link to which the redirect will be done if the user will succesfully login in
        loginUserControl.urlForRedirecting = getWishListLink();
    }
    else
        Response.Redirect(getWishListLink());

}
```

The problem is that, after the userr logs in succesfully, the url is null (but i've completed it already!!!)

```
Response.Redirect(this.urlForRedirecting);
```

Do you see why?

Answer (score 1):

You should always trim your values for username/passwords to remove white space.

```
 string user = txtUser.Text.Trim();
 string passwordMD5 = UtilsStatic.GetMD5Hash(txtPassword.Text.Trim());
```

I believe that GetMD5Hash will create diffrent values if you have "Value" vs " Value ".

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the line of code:

```
modal.Show();
```

Your user control will be shown and you set the value after this so it's not set when the form opens.

Try moving the code so that it's like:

```
ASP.usercontrols_loginpopup_ascx loginUserControl = (ASP.usercontrols_loginpopup_ascx)UtilsStatic.FindControlRecursive(Page, "loginPopUp");
loginUserControl.urlForRedirecting = getWishListLink();
ModalPopupExtender modal = (ModalPopupExtender)loginUserControl.FindControl("loginPopUp");
modal.Show();
```

This will set the urlForRedirecting property before you open the form, meaning you can access it once it's open.

Comment: Hi Fermin. I've moved the code but there is the same problem. However the urlForRedirecting is a property of loginUserControl so it does not depends on .show. Thanks for your suggestion, anyway.

Comment: Try making urlForRedirecting static as the value will be lost when you post back.

Comment: Your comment was helpfull. Although it does not answer my question, it gave me the ideea to use a static class for this kind of situations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewState between postbacks otherwise value of property will be lost.

```
public string UrlForRedirecting
{
    get
    {
        object urlForRedirecting = ViewState["UrlForRedirecting"];
        if (urlForRedirecting != null)
        {
            return urlForRedirecting as string;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    set
    {
        ViewState["UrlForRedirecting"] = value;
    }
}
```